# Equal length for input and output of signature generation

Tags: encryption, signing

I want to generate digital signature on a text of length *300 bit*, add some new text to the obtained signature, and then sign the resulting text.

I have used Bouncy Castle functions and realized that in the RSA signature scheme, the size of the key must be greater than input length. The obtained output length was equal to key size and by a adding new text, key size must be greater. But, I want to use **one key** for signing.
For example I first started using of 512-bit key but for second signing I must use 1024-bit key whereas I have one key for signing.

How should I do it? Is it possible (in Java or any language)?

Comment: is this what you are trying to do? Sign(Sign(text)+new_text) AND you want to do both the "Sign" with one key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on using only the `512-bit` key, the maximum data length you can sign is up to `53 bytes=424 bits` in **one shot**, so you have to split the data and sign it separately.
For example - 
Suppose your data length before doing the second signing is `500 bits`, then
split it into two sets - `424 bits`  and `66 bits`. And then sign these two separately and concatenate the result. 

**EDIT**
There is one more way you can do it, using only **1 key** -

- Have a key size of `2048 bits`. You can sign data up to length of `245 bytes=1960bits`.
- After the first sign operation and addition of additional information i,e after Sign(data)+info, perform a
  **SHA-512** digest on the result. This will compress the result to **64 bytes.**
- Then again sign it
  with the same key.
  In short - `Sign(SHA-1(Sign(data)+info))`

  NOTE : You can do the the above signing with a key length of `1024-bit` also.

Comment: thanks for your response. But if I use 1024-bit key, output length will be 1024 bit and for second signing, greater key must be used.

Comment: @leylamoazami : yeah that's true. Then you can try out the second method that I have told i.e splitting. I have deleted the first method from the answer.

Comment: @leylamoazami : If you want to use RSA to sign then splitting is the only method. Split - Sign - Concatenate(join)

Comment: @leylamoazami : Why are you signing it two times? I am just asking because if I know the reason I might be able to give a better solution.

Comment: Because I am simulating micropayment and any one that obtain coin, must add some informations to it and sign it and transfer the coin to another. Thanks, I will try your solution.

Comment: Oh, this solution doesn't work because I want sign the coin with its information, So this information must with the coin to be signed. sign (coin + information). If coin is signed apart from information, then signature will not to be proof.

Comment: nevertheless, Signature scheme isn't important for me.

Comment: @leylamoazami : I have edited the answer with another method. Tell me what you think about it.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to have a signature that can be recoverable and by use of hash it isn't recoverable.

Comment: @leylamoazami : I think there should be a better way of doing it. Signing it two times seems redundant. What if you just do Sign(data+info)?

Comment: No,  I am working on simulate microPayment in peer to peer networks. Each user in networks who wants to pay to another user, must sign X=(own coin + some information) one time and transfer it to another user. The user that receive the coin, for payment to another user, must sign (X + some information) and transfer to another.

Comment: @leylamoazami : so are all the user's have the same key?

Comment: No, each user has own key but each user may be first signer or second signer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write a simple algorithm that creates another(Virtual Sign for you) by simply encrypting the Sign into some code and then using both of them.

It will solve two purposes for you.

- You'll have both different signatures
- You will be able to use The One and Only key that you have

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: I didn't understand what you mean. I want to use Standard Signing Function.